# MS Access 365 attachment problem. Cannot save it directly

Tags: database, ms-access, attachment

I have access database, where I store the word document as attachment.
I know it is not ideal, but it previously worked without any problems.

Now when I open the database, and try to edit the attachment it used to open it in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\ folder and I was able to edit it directly and then save it in database directly.
For some reason from last week I cannot do so, and it always ask me to save as to local drive without saving in to database.

Please see below the pictures of the steps:

Database Table:
[image: Database Table]

Database permissions:
[image: Database permissions]

Open Attachments:
[image: Open Attachments]

Edit word document and save it:
[image: Edit word document and save it:]

It used to save it in temporary folder INetCache and than save it directly to database.
But now it asked me to save as to local drive:

Save as to local drive:
[image: Save as to local drive:]

I can see the the word document is open in the correct folder:
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\

Word documents in INetCache:
[image]

I also added it this location to trusted location:
[image: trusted location]

Can someone help me what changed?

I cannot edit it directly and save it as attachment any more.

Thank you.

Peter.